# What defines an isomorphism of two groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, group-isomorphism

While showing isomorphism of two groups what are the necessary conditions do I need to show, onto property with 1-1 and homomorphism or one-one + showing homomorphism will suffice.

I am getting confused between these two where to show onto and where to not for, *e.g.*, consider two groups $G=(Z,+)$ and $G'=(...., -2m,-m,0,m,2m....., +)$ I define a mapping $f:G \to G' : f(a)=ma$ $\forall a\in G$. Now here in order to show isomorphism do I need to show onto property also or one-one and homomorphism is sufficient

Comment: Be a bit careful -- a "$2$-group" is itself an algebraic object. I've edited your question to avoid this ambiguity. As for your question, it's worth reviewing the definition of an isomorphism: "An isomorphism is a [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism) that is _also_ a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection)". Nothing more, nothing less. If you want, you can break down "bijection" into its constituent parts as well, and say "An isomorphism is a homomorphism that is injective and surjective".

Comment: You have to show three things. First, that $f$ is a homomorphism. Second, that $f$ is onto. Third, that $f$ is injective. Do a few more examples.

Comment: What you need to show is that it is a homomorphism and is *bijective*. The bijection can be established by separately showing that it is one-to-one and onto; or by showing it has a two-sided inverse. What may be confusing is that whenever you have a one-to-one homomorphism $f\colon G\to K$, this will establish an isomorphism between $G$ and *its image* $f(G)$; but $f(G)$ in general is just a subgroup of $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to show that two groups, $G$ and $H$, are isomorphic, is to show that there is a homomorphism $f:G\to H$ such that there exists a homomorphism $g:H\to G$ with

$$f\circ g={\rm id}_H\quad\text{and}\quad g\circ f={\rm id}_G,$$

where ${\rm id}_X$ is the identity map on $X$.

This definition is borrowed from category theory and it illustrates an overarching idea.

In the case of group theory, it is indeed equivalent to showing *all* of the following:

- $f$ is onto,
- $f$ is one-to-one, and
- $f$ is a homomorphism.

This is a pleasant exercise.